# DecimalFormat not working with Math.PI

Tags: java, decimalformat

I'm having a seemingly minor bit of trouble with a certain method in a class I'm writing to do simple area equations. Here's the method in question.

```
    public static double CircleArea()
 {
  Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
  DecimalFormat formater = new DecimalFormat("##00.00");
  System.out.print("Please enter the radius of the circle: ");
  double radius = scanner.nextDouble();
  double area = Math.PI * (radius * radius);
  System.out.println("The area of circle is: " + area);
  return 0;
 }
```

Now, with all my other methods, it seems to be working just fine, however with this one, it doesn't limit the format at two decimal places. I'd appreciate any help I can get for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you did not use the formatter, try this

```
    String str = new DecimalFormat("0.00").format(area);
    System.out.println(str);
```

or a simpler version

```
System.out.printf("The area of circle is: %.2f%n", area);
```